# Ext JS loadRecord into form combo box

Tags: extjs

I have a grid in my application and i want to populate the form once the grid selection is changed. I am using method loadRecord() on my form and it works pretty fine for all fields except the combo box. The id for combo box from the selection as well as combo box ids are in  attached properly.

The combobox config:

```
{ 
   xtype: 'combobox', 
   fieldLabel: this.T('dep_type'), 
   name: 'type_id', 
   displayField:'name', 
   valueField:'id', 
   editable: false, 
   forceSelection: true, 
   store: 'main.department.components.Types' 
}
```

Could you please assist on this issue.

Comment: I'm sure you mean `loadRecord()`. Can you share the config of your combobox?

Comment: `{
 xtype: 'combobox',
 fieldLabel: this.T('dep_type'),
 name: 'type_id',
 displayField:'name',
 valueField:'id',
 editable: false,
 forceSelection: true,
 store: 'main.department.components.Types'
 
}`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Some guesses:

1. there is no value for this field from the selected record
2. there is no field named "type_id" from the selected record
3. the name of the field from the selected record and the name of the form field do not match (same as #2)

Answer (score 0):

first of all assign an ID to your combobox.

after that `Ext.getCmp('yourComboBoxId').getStore().load()` would help.